# Dynamic Data Display

Tags: wpf

I can't load the Applications which are get it from this link. I am going to create a many charts in Wpf by the help of Dynamic Data Display and i have seen some samples on below link but can't able to load atleast any one of them. Can any body try this, plz help me if u knw.

https://d3future.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/src/DynamicDataDisplay.Samples/Demos

It will be great help.

Regards:- 
Rajanikanth

Comment: Click the download link at the top. It will download a 10+ meg file that will include all of the source code.

Comment: I have downloaded the source code from that link, However it is not compiling. I am receiving the "operation could destabilize the run time" error. Should I do anything specific to make the code compile. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to click on the Download button, as shown in the image:

[image]

UPDATE>>>>>>>>

Please note that this is just a library, there no Main application to launch it ! You have just to make a reference to it, and then use it in your own application.

Here is what I found in the readme file:

**WPF Dynamic Data Display' is a library of WPF controls for dynamic data visualization.
Homepage - http://www.codeplex.com/dynamicdatadisplay/
Blog - http://microsoft.cs.msu.su/Blog/thecentury/default.aspx (mostly in Russian for now)
Twitter - http://twitter.com/DynamicDataDisp
If you have questions, bug reports or feature requests, you can post them at 'Discussions' page at our codeplex site or 
e-mail them to d3@mslab.cs.msu.su**

Comment: I did that, However source codes are not compiling. What should I do to compile and see the running application.